# DateTime to RFC-1123 gives inaccurate timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, rfc822, rfc1123

If I get the RFC-1123 formatted date of a DateTime object, it gives the current local time, but gives the timezone as GMT (which is inaccurate).
`DateTime.Now.ToString("r");`
returns
`Fri, 12 Feb 2010 16:23:03 GMT`

At 4:23 in the afternoon, but my timezone is UTC+10 (plus, we're currently observing daylight saving time).

Now, I can get a return value that's "correct" by converting to UTC first:
`DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r");`
returns
`Fri, 12 Feb 2010 05:23:03 GMT`

However, ideally, I'd like to get the right timezone, which I guess would be
`Fri, 12 Feb 2010 16:23:03 +1100`

Passing in the current CultureInfo doesn't change anything. I could get a UTC offset with TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(...) and format a timezone string from that, but stripping out the GMT bit and replacing it seems gratutiously messy.

Is there a way to force it to include the correct timezone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET implementation always expresses the result as if it were GMT, irrespective of the time offset of the actual date.

By using `DateTime.Now.ToString("r");` you're essentially saying `String.Format("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'", DateTime.Now);`, which is the .NET RFC1123 format string, as indicated on MSDN - [The RFC1123 ("R", "r") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#RFC1123).

To get the behaviour you require, you should probably use `String.Format`, and replace the fixed 'GMT' section of the specifier with a time offset specifier:

- [The "z" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zSpecifier)
- [The "zz" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzSpecifier)
- [The "zzz" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier)

Answer (score 4):

You could just do `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString ("R")`, you will still get GMT timezone but the time is correctly offset then.

Comment: This is correct ,however, you still must replace the time zone. This is what I have used knowing my server is EST. date.ToLocalTime().ToString("R").Replace("GMT", "EST")
If you are looking to modify the date header in a web request, you can use this. I'm using this in dev & prod, it works. MethodInfo priMethod = client.Headers.GetType().GetMethod("AddWithoutValidate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            priMethod.Invoke(client.Headers, new object[] { "Date", <conversion shown above>);